How to duplicate the Node entity?
I want to create a word comparison dictionary.
Maybe an HTML table like the following isn't good because there are too many columns for a screen responsive table.



English
Chinese
Japanese
Korean
Mongolian




Hello
你好
こんにちは
안녕하세요
Сайн уу



I can create a node bundle named Words and then add a node for each English word and then add translations for each such node but because there are about 5,000 words to compare, this will inflate the number of my nodes tremendously, so I thought about creating a separate entity which is not Node but rather Word that will behave exactly like Node in anything.
How to duplicate the Node entity?

Does this Drupal documentation answer your question? https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/entity-api/creating-a-custom-content-entity

@monalisa I am not sure because the entity I want to create is not bundle-less (as mentioned there), rather just as there are Node bundles there would be Word bundles, in this case.

Making a custom entity bundle-able is easy. It is just an extension of defining a custom entity. https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/entity-api/create-a-custom-content-entity-with-bundles

Node is the most popular and extended entity in the Drupal ecosystem.  So you can't just copy it by changing the name and have all the same features.
5,000 additional nodes vs. 5,000 custom entities will probably not be a huge difference in performance, although it's impossible to say without more details.  So instead of copying the Node entity, I would suggest adding custom content types and then adding bundle classes if necessary to add custom methods to the Word content types.
If you do decide to create a custom entity instead, I would not try to copy the Node entity code.  Instead, I would start with drush: drush generate content:entity provides some useful prompts and boilerplate code.  In particular, this allows you to create simplified entities that do not have revisioning, translations, and so on, which can improve performance.
